# Asp.net list property of model gets lost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In asp.net Web API I got a model which has a list as property.

```
public class MyModel {
        [Key, Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

After running the seed method successfully, when I check the table's data in the Server Explorer, there's only this property `Title`, but `MyList` isn't displayed.

When I enter `/api/MyModel/potato` in the address bar and have a look at the debug window in my controller, Visual Studio tells that the `MyList` property of the potato object would be null, but it is not actually.

How can I access MyList?

**Update**: Here's the Seed method

```
protected override void Seed(MyProject.Models.MyProjectContext context)
{
    context.MyModels.AddOrUpdate(
        m => m.Title,
        new MyModel {
            Title = "potato",
            MyList = new List<string>() {
                "Foo",
                "Bar"
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: post your fill list method code.

Comment: `MyList` is not in your table because it doesn't have an appropriate `data type` for a database.

Comment: Updated the description with my Seed method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create 2 models to create a relationship SQL Server can actually create. And a Primary key should not be editable. If you change the title, you change the PK, which is never a good design.

```
public class MyModel
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string Title { get; set; }
  //set the relationship to MyList-class
  public virtual ICollection<MyList> MyList {get; set;}
}

public class MyList
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

With this you ensure, that every `MyClass` object has 0,1..n `MyList` objects.

And with this model you can call it in your Action via:

```
var result = context.MyClass.Include(o => o.Mylist);
//alternative
var result = context.MyClass.Include("MyList");
```